# Floating navigation in IE 7 and below?

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer

I'm working on a website for my Dad and can't seem to fix the one thing I have left to do.

The website is http://www.tendonaid.com

The problem is that in IE7 and below, the navigation floats off to the left, and it looks horrible. Unfortunately, his target audience is older gentlemen (the product relieves tendon pain), who may be unfamiliar with technology and as such, rarely, if ever, update their browsers. They are also very likely to have Internet Explorer.

Help?

I hate Internet Explorer.

Comment: off topic: 1.3MB image 3,072px × 2,304px (scaled to 300px × 225px). Really??

Comment: It looks fine to me in IE7. Only in *quirks* mode (equivalent of IE5.5) does the navigation float off to the left. And as less then 10% of the world use IE6 I really wouldn't worry about it. Microsoft's own site: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to the links breaking to the next line, you are seeing the line-break due to the width of your `.lavalamp` class.  Increase the width of that element and it will keep all of them on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try and make your pa happy with conditional css which can load styles depending on the version of ie you're using as follows.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-7.0.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The above example will load the file ie-7.0.css only if the user is using ie7. 
If you google 'conditional css for ie' you'll find many more examples.

Good luck and I hope your dad likes the final site :)